# Экспорт функции из длл

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь экспортировать функцию `STDAPI DllGetClassObject(REFCLSID,REFIID,PPVOID)`,  но экспортируется функция `DllGetClassObject@16`. Как зделать так, что бы компилятор не приписывал '@16'?  Пользуюсь IDE Code::Blocks.

`extern 'c'` уже определено в дефайне STDAPI.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте написать перед ней `extern "C"`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить в исходник прагму

```
#pragma comment( linker, "/export:DllGetClassObject" )
```